# Bypassing App Transport Security to allow unsecured HTTP server

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire, app-transport-security, moya

### Situation:

I have to connect to these two different servers for development and staging use. Both of the servers have unstrusted SSL certificates.
For example purposes, these two servers URL's are:

Staging server: `https://52.70.13.2:1010/`

Development server: `https://example.entrydns.org:1012`

Whenever I tried to call the API, i get empty response with following error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

or sometimes,

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

I use [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) for my network layers, which is basically just a nice wrapper for [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). For additional info, I use `XCode 7.3` and the app only supports `> iOS 9`.

### What I've did:

I am very well aware of App Transport Security issue that Apple want to enforce. I wanted to disable it for development but still in vain. Some of the ways I tried to bypass the ATS it are as the following:

1. Add the following in my `plist` to allow arbitrary loads.

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   ```
2. Explicitly defines the domain exceptions.

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
           <key>example.entrydns.org</key>
           <dict>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
               <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
               <true/>
               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <true/>
               <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
               <string>TLSv1.1</string>
               <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
               <false/>
               <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <true/>
               <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
               <string>TLSv1.1</string>
               <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
               <false/>
           </dict>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

Here's the screenshot for my `plist`:
[image]

3. I also tried to disable the Server Trust Policy of Alamofire manager shared instance. Here's the example code:

   ```
   // Disable Policies
   let policies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
       "https://example.entrydns.org:1012/": .DisableEvaluation,
       "https://52.70.13.2:1010/": .DisableEvaluation
   ]

   let manager = Manager(
       configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
       serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: policies)
   )
    // ---------------
   let networkLogger = NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true, responseDataFormatter: nil)

   let endpointClosure = { (target: ExampleAPI) -> Endpoint<ExampleAPI> in      
       let url = target.baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(target.path).absoluteString
       let endpoint: Endpoint<ExampleAPI> = Endpoint<ExampleAPI>
               (URL: url,
                sampleResponseClosure: {.NetworkResponse(200, target.sampleData)},
                method: target.method,
                parameters: target.parameters,
                parameterEncoding: .URLEncodedInURL)
       return endpoint.endpointByAddingHTTPHeaderFields(target.header())
   }

   let ExampleProvider = MoyaProvider<ExampleAPI>(manager: manager,
                                          plugins:[networkLogger],
                                          endpointClosure: endpointClosure)
   ```
4. Open the URLs and download the certs on my device and simulators.

Even after all the steps above I still got the same error. Any takes on what I did wrong and what I can do to solve this problem? BTW, it would be great if I can avoid server-side solution.

Thanks in advance.

#### References:

- https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: you tried to delete all of your exceptions domains field from plist and leave only NSAllowsArbitraryLoads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your policies with just the hostname.

```
// Disable Policies
let policies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "example.entrydns.org": .DisableEvaluation
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I subclass `ServerTrustPolicyManager` in order to handle self-signed https certification.

```
internal class MyServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {
    // In order to trust all self-signed https certifications.
    open override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
        return ServerTrustPolicy.disableEvaluation
    }
}
```

Then, create a custom `SessionManager` with above `ServerTrustPolicyManager`.

```
// Create a `SessionManager` of Alamofire based on custom trust policy manager
func getHttpManager(timeout: TimeInterval) -> SessionManager {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = timeout

    sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    // Use customize policy
    let trustPolicies = MyServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [:])

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: SessionDelegate(), serverTrustPolicyManager: trustPolicies)
    return manager
}
```